# Test::mysqld won't close mysqld as expected

Tags: perl, unit-testing, mysql

I have this script:

```
#!/var/home/cherry/opt/perl

use Test::More;
use DBI;
use Test::mysqld;
use Data::Dumper;

my $mysqld = Test::mysqld->new(
    base_dir => '/tmp/test_mysqls',
    my_cnf => {
        'skip-networking' => '', # no TCP socket
    }
) or plan skip_all => $Test::mysqld::errstr;

my $dbh = DBI->connect(
    $mysqld->dsn(dbname => 'test'),
);

warn Dumper($mysqld);

done_testing();
```

When I run this, here's the output I get:

```
prove -lv t/test.t
t/test.t .. $VAR1 = bless( {
                 '_owner_pid' => 21854,
                 'base_dir' => '/tmp/test_mysqls',
                 'pid' => 21918,
                 'mysql_install_db' => '/usr/bin/mysql_install_db',
                 'auto_start' => 2,
                 'my_cnf' => {
                               'tmpdir' => '/tmp/test_mysqls/tmp',
                               'pid-file' => '/tmp/test_mysqls/tmp/mysqld.pid',
                               'skip-networking' => '',
                               'datadir' => '/tmp/test_mysqls/var',
                               'socket' => '/tmp/test_mysqls/tmp/mysql.sock'
                             },
                 'mysqld' => '/usr/sbin/mysqld'
               }, 'Test::mysqld' );

1..0
```

---

The test never completes. The script waits on a newline for ever and never exits -- when I do ps aux, I can see the instance of mysqld running even after I do ctrl + c. I don't even know where to begin to troubleshoot this issue. Any hints?

Comment: What is calling `Data::Dumper` and printing out the `Test::mysqld` contents?

Comment: One second... lemme make a quick edit. Sorry 'bout that.

Comment: If I do: $mysqld->stop(9); it stops msyqld. Would anyone consider that an acceptable solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding a do {} and invoking $mysqld->stop inside an eval {} to shut down the mysqld.

```
my $mysqld = Test::mysqld->new(
    base_dir => '/tmp/test_mysqls',
    my_cnf => {
        'skip-networking' => '', # no TCP socket
    }
) or do {
    eval { $mysqld->stop };
    plan skip_all => $Test::mysqld::errstr;
};
```